# Euler's "On transcendental progressions..." [E19]

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, gamma-function, infinite-product

I'm studying Euler's paper *["On transcendental progressions, or those for which the general term is not given algebraically"](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//docs/translations/E019en.pdf)* (marked as [E19] in The Euler Archive), and I'm trying to understand the following fragment:

> I was looking for a general expression which would give all the terms of the progression
>      $$1 \;+\; 1\!\cdot\!2 \;+\; 1\!\cdot\!2\!\cdot\!3 \;+\; 1\!\cdot\!2\!\cdot\!3\!\cdot\!4 \;+\; etc.$$
>   Supposing that, if continued to infinity, this progression would ultimately behave like a geometric progression, I came upon the following expression
>   $$\frac{1\cdot2^n}{1+n} \cdot \frac{2^{1-n}\cdot3^n}{2+n} \cdot \frac{3^{1-n}\cdot4^n}{3+n} \cdot \frac{4^{1-n}\cdot5^n}{4+n} \cdot etc.,$$
>   which represents the term of order $n$ of the stated progression.

My questions are:

1. **Why** did Euler say that this progression of factorials would ultimately behave like a **geometric progression** when continued to infinity?
2. How could it lead him from that idea to the **infinite product** he shows in the very next line? How is it related to the geometric progression he was talking about? I can't see the connection right away.